# como llenar un combo hecho directiva, desde AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quiero en un formulario dinámico poder establecerle un valor a un Combo (Select), sinembargo cuando los controles dinámicos son renderizados, el combo, el cual es una directiva, no precarga el valor que se le envía.

Me gustaría saber como poder resolver este tema. El código está abajo y a referencio también el ejemplo en [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/g9FGXJGzGEQ38fE6czRN?p=preview). Al cargar la pagina o al agregar nuevas filas, el combo no deja seleccionado el valor que viene en el JSON.

https://plnkr.co/edit/g9FGXJGzGEQ38fE6czRN?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="shanidkvApp">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <title>Tittle</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>AngularJS Dynamic Form Fields</h3>
            <hr />
            <div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
                    <select ng-model="choice.mobile">
                        <option value="Mobile" >Mobile</option>
                        <option value="Office" >Office</option>
                        <option value="Home" >Home</option> 
                    </select>

                    <sel caremonda="choice.res" opciones="paises"></sel>
                    <input type="text"  value="{{choice.res}}">
                    <input type="{{choice.type}}" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter mobile number">
                    <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
                </fieldset>
                <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>
                <button class="addfields" ng-click="mostrar()">Mostrar</button>

                <div id="choicesDisplay">
                    {{ choices }}
                </div>

                <select ng-model="multipleSelect">
                    <option value="var1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="var2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="var3">Option 3</option>
                </select><br>
                <tt>multipleSelect = {{multipleSelect}}</tt><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu problema esta que al hacer click en mostrar, siempre te muestra la misma residencia y no cambia dependiendo tu elección?

Comment: no, el problema esta en que cada vez que cargo la pagina en el Json inicial trae una recidencia pero en el combo no queda seleccionado, al igual al agregar nuevas filas, el combo no carga la que tiene el atributo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la directiva [ngSelected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) en las opciones del `select`, esta directiva se guía por una expresión para marcar una opción como `selected`:

```
<option ng-repeat="facility in countries" value="{{facility.value}}" ng-selected="facility.value == leValor">{{facility.name}}</option>
```